# Should we clean up the tags?

Tags: discussion

for example we currently have baking x27, but also baker x4, bakery x2
baking-node x2, and solo-baking x2, probably don't need all 5 tags.

I think a single baking tag enough, but maybe also a solo-baking?

How does an admin properly go about merging, retagging questions, and deleting redundant tags?

Answer (score 2):

I think i do now have the ability to create tag synonyms. I am not sure if that is the best way to address that.

Also i can retag articles to clean things up also so that should help too.

Comment: not sure best place to have discussion on which tags should be merged